# Java - how to remove last comma from json array?

Tags: java, json

i have json array and when i parse it in java,

```
[{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2,text:"test2"},{id:3,text:"test3"},]
```

it gives error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value at 3 is null.
```

i tried but don't complete...

```
   for (int k = 0; k < array.length(); k++) {

        if (!array.getJSONObject(k).equals("") && !array.getJSONObject(k).equals(null)) {// this condition gives error

          JSONObject objNext = array.getJSONObject(k);
          if (objNext != null && objNext.has("id")) {

          }
        }
   }
```

Comment: If possible you should instead fix the JSON - trailing commas are not part of the spec.

Comment: but it's dynamic from remove sources...

Comment: `jsonStr.replace(",]", "]")`

Comment: @11thdimension that will work for the data given but if there's whitespace it will fail. Regex might be better - `jsonStr.replace(",\\s*]", "]")`

Comment: I probably will tell not very popular thought, but I prefer to fix errors rather than write workarounds. In your case you try to get a workaround and not to fix the error, Your error means: "please fix source json (let the system which generated json will produce correct json that will meet specifications)".